# React Native Passing a component to a component

Tags: javascript, react-native, components

I am new to react native and am not sure how i can pass components between components.

I have created a set of functions capable of generating a table. I am trying to make the table more general by allowing `entryData` to be components as well as strings or numeric types.

If `useTextWrapper` is true and the type of `entryData` is number or string then the table will put the data in a text component. Otherwise, I assume that the `entryData` must be a component and then I simply want to unpack `entryData` within the view component. Here is what I have tried so far and i get a "Text strings must be rendered within text components". Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

```
function EntryDataWrapper(props) {
    return <View> {props.children} </View>;
}
function RowEntry(props) {
    let {entryStyle, entryTextStyle, entryData, useTextWrapper} = props;
    const theType = typeof entryData;
    return (
        <View style={entryStyle}>
            {useTextWrapper && (theType == 'nuber' || theType == 'string') ? (
                <Text style={entryTextStyle}>{entryData}</Text>
            ) : (
                <EntryDataWrapper> {entryData} </EntryDataWrapper>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: For what I see in the code sample, you are doing something similar on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20084) thread. Check if that is the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message already said the issue.  `Text strings must be rendered within text components`. EntryDataWrapper component didn't do that.

So you should add the Text component into it. please follow below code.

```
     function EntryDataWrapper(props) {
        return <View> <Text>{props.children}</Text> </View>;
     }
    function RowEntry(props) {
        let {entryStyle, entryTextStyle, entryData, useTextWrapper} = props;
        const theType = typeof entryData;
        return (
            <View style={entryStyle}>
                {useTextWrapper && (theType == 'nuber' || theType == 'string') ? (
                    <Text style={entryTextStyle}>{entryData}</Text>
                ) : (
                    <EntryDataWrapper> {entryData} </EntryDataWrapper>
                )}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Cheer!